# Unable to find module error when trying to execute protractor tests

Tags: module, jasmine, protractor, frameworks

I have created a sample framework and am trying to login to my application

Below is a screenshot of my package structure

[image: Framework Structure]

This is my LoginObjects.js which is present inside Pages folder
[image: Login Objects]

I am accessing this in my Spec\Login.js folder
[image]

When I execute my configuration.js I am getting this below error. Please let me know where I am going wrong

Failures:

1. Testing Login Page encountered a declaration exception

Message:

```
Error: Cannot find module './Pages/LoginObjects'

Require stack:

- C:\Users\silpa\eclipse-workspace_udemy_js\Nextgen\Specs\Login.js

- C:\Users\silpa\eclipse-workspace_udemy_js\Nextgen\node_modules\jasmine\lib\jasmine.js

- C:\Users\silpa\eclipse-workspace_udemy_js\Nextgen\node_modules\protractor\built\frameworks\jasmine.js

- C:\Users\silpa\eclipse-workspace_udemy_js\Nextgen\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js

- C:\Users\silpa\eclipse-workspace_udemy_js\Nextgen\node_modules\protractor\built\launcher.js

- C:\Users\silpa\eclipse-workspace_udemy_js\Nextgen\node_modules\protractor\built\cli.js

- C:\Users\silpa\eclipse-workspace_udemy_js\Nextgen\node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor
```

Stack:

```
Error: Cannot find module './Pages/LoginObjects'

Require stack:

- C:\Users\silpa\eclipse-workspace_udemy_js\Nextgen\Specs\Login.js

- C:\Users\silpa\eclipse-workspace_udemy_js\Nextgen\node_modules\jasmine\lib\jasmine.js

- C:\Users\silpa\eclipse-workspace_udemy_js\Nextgen\node_modules\protractor\built\frameworks\jasmine.js

- C:\Users\silpa\eclipse-workspace_udemy_js\Nextgen\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js

- C:\Users\silpa\eclipse-workspace_udemy_js\Nextgen\node_modules\protractor\built\launcher.js

- C:\Users\silpa\eclipse-workspace_udemy_js\Nextgen\node_modules\protractor\built\cli.js

- C:\Users\silpa\eclipse-workspace_udemy_js\Nextgen\node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor

    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)

    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)

    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)

    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)

    at Suite.<anonymous> (C:\Users\silpa\eclipse-workspace_udemy_js\Nextgen\Specs\Login.js:5:15)

    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\silpa\eclipse-workspace_udemy_js\Nextgen\Specs\Login.js:2:1)

    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
```

1 spec, 1 failure

Finished in 2.136 seconds

Answer (score 0):

you need to get out of the Specs folder first, then get in the Pages one.
Try with `'../Pages/LoginObjects'`